# can previous installation partition be made bootable

Tags: installation, 12.04, upgrade

OK, ranting and raving won't get me anywhere.
I installed 12.04 and all my previous stuff was there and worked. I was trying to tweak it and followed some bad advice and screwed it up. I then re-installed 11.10 and that installation created a new partition, I can still access all my stuff on the other partition but what I'd really like to do is for ubuntu to boot into the partition where all my stuff is and for everything to work like it used to. Is that possible?

Comment: When you boot up, do you get a Grub screen (choice of boot options)?

Comment: Hello & thanks. Yes, but just comes back to the same version on the new partition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming your GRUB is working fine, and you are booting into the 'new' install on another partition somehow.  Yet your old partition still exists.

You can edit your 'working' grub menu to point to the other boot kernels located at /dev/sdXX/boot/vmlinuz-X.X.X-XX-XXXXXX

Basically, like the following:

menuentry 'RescueMePlz' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
   recordfail
   gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
   insmod gzio
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ext2
   set root='(hd0,msdos5)' 
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1d73dc63-beac-4c49-a8c7-f4efd6fe3cb7
   linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0.24-generic root=/dev/mapper/somediskgroupvg-rootv ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
   initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0.24-generic
}

where --set=root  is your UUID or device path

you can run `sudo blkid` to find your previous /boot device's uuid value (or cheat by looking at your OLD grub.cfg)

important that you set the -set=root  correctly

hope that gets you started.

Comment: Hello & thanks for the info. Unfortunately I don't understand any of what you're saying. How do I edit the working grub menu? Thanks.

Comment: Well...  your working grub menu would probably be located at /boot/grub/grub.cfg -- you can sudo vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg then look at the file.  If you're not comfortable with editing this file, I would be very careful doing so.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again